# How can I unset / remove a paragraph component from within template_preprocess_node?

Tags: theming, paragraphs

In Drupal 7, I need to be able to selectively remove paragraph components from a given node. Which parts of the $variables array need to be unset?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easily it seems. Something like the following does the job for removing the first component, for example:

`function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    unset($variables['content']['field_landing_page_components'][0]);
  }`